# Why i can not delete these dismissible widget from list

Tags: flutter

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, unnecessary_brace_in_string_interps

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shopapp/providers/cart.dart';

class CartCheckoutItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final double price;
  final String productId;
  final int quantity;
  final String title;
  CartCheckoutItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.productId,
    required this.price,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.title,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Key zorunlu parametresi ile kaydırma animasyonu eklenmesini sağlar
    return Dismissible(
      key: ValueKey(id),
      background: Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.delete,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 40.0,
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 15,
          vertical: 4,
        ),
      ),
      direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
      onDismissed: (direction) {
        Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false).removeItem(productId);
      },
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 15,
          vertical: 4,
        ),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: FittedBox(
                child: Text('\$${price}'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(title),
          subtitle: Text('Total: \$${price * quantity}'),
          trailing: Text('$quantity x'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

(A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree.
Make sure to implement the onDismissed handler and to immediately remove the Dismissible widget from the application once that handler has fired. just want to delete item with dismissible from provider's list

Comment: Can you show how you create the list? It seems like the product is still part of the list that is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this error by just assigning `UniqueKey` to your widget rather than `ValueKey`.

Just make it from

```
Dismissible(
      key: ValueKey(id),
```

to

```
Dismissible(
      key: UniqueKey(),
```

`UniqueKey` forces a widget to build every time the widget renders.